# Javascript Large String storing in code vs. storing in a dom object (such as a <pre> , <div>)

Tags: javascript, string, dom

I have a large javascript string. 
var s = '...............'; // this is about 32000 characters long.

if you wonder: that bit of javascript is autogenerated.

Does anybody know if it is better to store it outside of the javascript 
For instance in a dom object in the html page and then retrieve it
(e.g. var s = document.getElementById('hiddenTextArea').value; ) 
or is it okay to leave it in the javascript ?

note: I am not interested in the cost occurred in downloading the large string.
The question is really if it is okay to store a large string inside the javascript or not 
and whether there are better ways

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Storing it in the javascript itself will should always be more performant as you won't have to go through the DOM to retrieve the value.

Comment: I agree that 'should be more performant' 
but 'will it be ?' 
do you know for sure ? 
There is a big gotcha here and that is that my string is incredibly large.

Comment: It definately will be more performant. Storing in DOM just adds overhead, when you fetch it from the it still has to be stored internally somehow.

Comment: it is a word if we use it and we understand what we mean by it.

Comment: Definitely funner to use words we grok, whether or not they are in a dictionary.